# How to use watch expressions in chrome dev tools to watch variables in an angular component (properties of 'this' object)?

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to debug a property which is in an Angular 6 component. Naturally it is called in code trough `this` variable -> `this.model`. I am debugging it at the moment and would like to add it as a watch expression in Chrome dev tools so I can see how it changes trough the execution of the code. I tried just adding `this.model` as a watch expression, however it returns undefined, as `this` refers to the `window` object, which doesn't have a `model` property, so I am getting `undefined` on my watch expression.

What would be the proper way to watch `this.model`?

Comment: See also [Live Expressions](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/08/devtools#watch). Same idea as Watch Expressions, but in the Console. This feature doesn't solve the issue around `this`... you need to find a stable reference to the component's scope. It's just another way to monitor values which you might prefer over Watch Expressions.

Answer (score 4):

since the code is transpiled to js while executing, the reference of `this` changes. You can watch the `_this` instead. It will give you the instance of the component/service that you want to debug.

Answer (score 3):

use [Augury](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/augury/elgalmkoelokbchhkhacckoklkejnhcd?hl=en)

It logs all controller variables.

Answer (score 0):

There is one alternative but a little complex way also there by using a life cycle hook `DoCheck`. It keeps invoking a custom change-detection function `ngDoCheck()`.

So, create this function in your component class and add `console.log` inside it.
Eg:

```
ngDoCheck() {
    console.log(this.numberGiven);
  }
```

Finally, just add a breakpoint inside this function whenever you want to watch any variable [as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdpyw.png).